# Dragging Formula should increase cell reference after a specified count in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, ms-office

I have this data

```
    O
5  421
6  422
7  423
```

What i Want it in P Column

```
     P
 5  421
 6  421
 7  421
 8  421
 9  421
10  421
11  421
12  421
13  422
14  422
15  422
16  422
17  422
18  422
19  422
20  422
21  423
22  423
23  423
24  423
25  423
26  423
27  423
28  423
```

The same number increment is 8 times, then the next number comes and the repeat is same.
I have been trying but could not solve the issue. Plz Guide

Comment: does it all need to be the same formula? i.e. is it an issue if the top number is hard-coded and the rest is a formula?

Comment: @dhumphreys in P5 you can put  '=O5'  and it will return 421 Simply... then P6 must be a formula...

Comment: Will the number in Column O always increase by 1? Or the number can be random in Column O, and you want to restructure the list in Column O in Column P so that each number shows in 8 rows in the same order as in Column O?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX:

```
=INDEX(O:O,INT((ROW($ZZ1)-1)/8)+5)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect Idea... Super Answer. Thanks Scott

Answer (score 0):

If you want it all in the formula in column P, you could reference `ROWS`, i.e. if you put `=ROUND(ROW()*(1/8)-(1/8),0)+420` in cell P5, then you can just drag it down.

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, but the number 421 could be a different number and the sequence of this number is not sure, i just want to extract the value from another cell as given in the question. this solution will not fit for the requirements...